# Optimal all-around character builds

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I'm looking for a good build for Scarlett and Roderick in Divinity: Original Sin (first playthrough). I want to experience as much as possible of the content, so the goal is to cover as many areas as possible, which means between the two main characters I want:

- Loremaster
- Crafting & Blacksmithing
- The four elemental magic lines
- An ability to get to hard to reach places (such as **Tactical Retreat** from the Marksman line)
- Lucky Find
- Sneaking, Pickpocketing and Lockpicking
- **Pet Pal** talent for the extra conversations
- High **perception** to spot hidden things

The best I could come up with so far are a Ranger (dexterity) and a customized caster (intelligence) build with the **Lone Wolf** talent.

I'm sure there are better combinations out there, what are they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've refined it down to the following, and am very pleased with it so far. This is without the Lone Wolf talent, so I get all four characters (and their dialogue).

### Roderick (Spotter, Talker, Looter, Thief)

Ranged (Bow/Crossbow) with Dexterity and Perception as main stats. This is the character I usually have active when opening containers or talking to NPCs. It was therefore also useful to have him be the one that picks locks and sneaks into rooms (and pockets).

#### Stats

- Dexterity
- Perception

#### Abilities

- Expert Marksman (with Tactical Retreat)
- Bow/Crossbow (Crossbows are hard to find early on, so put a point into Bows to start with)
- Lucky Charm
- Charisma
- Lockpicking
- Sneaking
- Pickpocketing
- Telekinesis

Bartering I've found quite unnecessary due to finding plenty of loot (usually more than I could trade to merchants). You also get some from traits and items, so I wouldn't spend points on this.

If you have spare points, put them into the defensive abilities or add another spell line.

#### Talents

- Pet Pal (I love these, and felt really sorry when I accidentally crushed a rat with a crate)
- Light Stepper
- All Skilled Up
- Arrow Recovery

#### Traits (bold means take this side)

- Pragmatic (Crafting) ⇔ **Romantic (Lucky Charm)**
- Altruistic (Reputation) ⇔ **Egotistical (Bartering)**
- Independent (Willpower) ⇔ **Obedient (Willpower from Leadership)**
- Righteous (Leadership) ⇔ **Renegade (Pickpocketing)**
- Bold (Initiative) ⇔ **Cautious (Sneaking)**
- **Spiritual (Fear Immunity)** ⇔ Materialistic (Loremaster)
- **Compassionate (Crit Chance)** ⇔ Heartless (Backstab Hit Chance)
- **Forgiving (Curse Immunity)** ⇔ Vindictive (+Hit on AoO)
- Blunt (Charm Immunity) ⇔ **Considerate (Charisma)**

### Scarlett (Elements, Crafting, Loremaster)

4-Element caster, Crafter, Blacksmith (for repairing) and Loremaster. As starting spells I strongly recommend Midnight Oil, Flare and the hydrosophist heal.

#### Stats

- Intelligence
- Speed

#### Abilities

- Aerotheurge
- Geomancer
- Hydrosophist
- Pyrokinetic
- Two-handed (Staff)
- Blacksmithing
- Crafting

I did not put any points into Loremaster, because it's easy to get the first point early on and then identify enough jewelry to boost the Loremaster skill to 2 or 3, which is all I've needed so far.

No points in Leadership either, although I ended up with quite a few from items and traits.

#### Talents

- Know-it-All
- Scientist
- All Skilled Up

#### Traits (bold means take this side)

- **Pragmatic (Crafting)** ⇔ Romantic (Lucky Charm)
- **Altruistic (Reputation)** ⇔ Egotistical (Bartering)
- **Independent (Willpower)** ⇔ Obedient (Willpower from Leadership)
- **Righteous (Leadership)** ⇔ Renegade (Pickpocketing)
- **Bold (Initiative)** ⇔ Cautious (Sneaking)
- Spiritual (Fear Immunity) ⇔ **Materialistic (Loremaster)**
- **Compassionate (Crit Chance)** ⇔ Heartless (Backstab Hit Chance)
- **Forgiving (Curse Immunity)** ⇔ Vindictive (+Hit on AoO)
- **Blunt (Charm Immunity)** ⇔ Considerate (Charisma)

Comment: Accepting this answer, as I'm now past level 10 and still very happy with these choices.

Comment: I went with dual lone wolves with a 2 hander man at arms/hydro/aero crafter and a bow/pyro/geo sneak thief/looter.

Comment: I would just say that All Skilled Up is a bit of a waste. You get (up to) 3 skill points per level but you get very few talents.

Answer (score -1):

On hard difficulties you have to be smarter with your skill points. Don't spend points on Lockpicking, Charisma, or Lore Master - you can get all the Lore Master points you need from gear. Crafting can also be handled by one of the NPC companions you don't use.